# Xunit, MOCK unitest error : Setup on method with 9 parameter(s) cannot invoke callback with different number of parameters (8)

Tags: c#, .net-core, moq

I'm very new to xunit unitest case writing. I changed a function and also, and I made some changes in unit test case. But I got the following error. I tried to fix the issue. But no hope.

```
System.ArgumentException : Invalid callback. Setup on method with 9 parameter(s) cannot invoke callback with different number of parameters (8).

Stack Trace: 
MethodCall.<SetReturnsResponse>g__ValidateCallback|22_1(Delegate callback)
MethodCall.SetReturnsResponse(Delegate valueFactory)
NonVoidSetupPhrase`2.Returns[T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8](Func`9 valueExpression)
GeneratedReturnsExtensions.ReturnsAsync[T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,TMock,TResult](IReturns`2 mock, Func`9 valueFunction)
CreateReportTests.ctor() line 39
```

I got the error from below  section

```
_ReportClientMock
                .Setup(m => m.CreateReportAsync(
                It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(),
                It.IsAny<Guid>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<IEnumerable<Guid>>(), It.IsAny<TimeSpan>(), It.IsAny<bool>()))

                .ReturnsAsync<string, string, string, string, Guid, string, IEnumerable<Guid>, TimeSpan, IReportClient, Report>
                ((entityType, entityId, appId, appContext, creatorId, report, UserIds, _) =>

               new Report(Guid.NewGuid(), entityType, entityId, appId, appContext, creatorId, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, null, report, false, UserIds));
```

Actual function is *

```
Task<Comment> CreateReportAsync(string entityType, string entityId, string appId, string? appContext, Guid creatorId, string report, IEnumerable<Guid>? UserIds, TimeSpan expirationTime, bool allow);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters in the setup need to match the ones of the method and that you use in the `ReturnAsync` statement. In your case, the setup matches the parameters of the method, but the lambda expression in `ReturnAsync` does not. If you change this to

```
_ReportClientMock
  .Setup(m => m.CreateReportAsync(
    It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(),
    It.IsAny<Guid>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<IEnumerable<Guid>>(), It.IsAny<TimeSpan>(), It.IsAny<bool>()))
  .ReturnsAsync<string, string, string, string, Guid, string, IEnumerable<Guid>, TimeSpan, bool>
    ((entityType, entityId, appId, appContext, creatorId, report, UserIds, _, _) =>
           new Report(Guid.NewGuid(), entityType, entityId, appId, appContext, creatorId, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, null, report, false, UserIds));
```

(note the second underscore in `(entityType, entityId, appId, appContext, creatorId, report, UserIds, _, _) => ...`)